# Error al conectar con MongoDB

Tags: nodejs

Trato de realizar una conexión con MongoDB usando typescript pero me aparece el siguiente error:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: facilita el copy paste de texto, en principio hay un error de EADDRINUSE lo cual puede indicar que el server node no levanta pues ya hay una instancia ; E = error, ADDR= dirección (ip) , INUSE = ya la está usando otro proceso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lees el mensaje que "EADDRINUSE :::4000" te esta diciendo que ya tienes ocupado el puerto 4000 por otra aplicación.

Lo que te puede estar pasando es que hayas finalizado mongo o nodejs y realmente no ha muerto y por tanto tiene el puerto cogido.

Puedes ver si el puerto esta cogido con el siguiente comando

**windows**

```
    netstat -na | find "4000"
```

**Linux**

```
    netstat -na | grep 4000
```

En el resultado si aparece el puerto te dira en que estado esta.
Creo que en linux con el comando lsof puedes saber quien lo esta utilizando.

Si estas en windows puedes ir al administrador de tares y matar el proceso.